# Cannot use computer after Linux mint goes to hibernate

Tags: macintosh, linux-mint, sleep, hibernate

I am running Linux Mint on my Laptop (MacBook Pro 2015 dual booting with Yosemite) however when I put my lid down I have the setting set to 'Hibernate'. The issue is when I put the lid down I cannot seem to wake the computer up again, all I get is a blank screen. I have tried to click the trackpad and type random letters on the keyboard (even tried the power button) but nothing works. The only response I get when I wake the computer up is a 'click' from the ForceTouch trackpad when I press on it.

Would I need to install some drivers or something to prevent this issue? If so what do I do to install it. If not what are the steps required to prevent the 'black screen of death' when waking my computer up from hibernation mode.

#### Here are my Error Logs:

[kern.log](http://1drv.ms/1Nug8nD)
[pm-powersave](http://1drv.ms/1KecpsA)
[pm-suspend.log](http://1drv.ms/1Kecr3u)
[syslog](http://1drv.ms/1JpsLJG)

Comment: Have you got a swap partition? If not you won't be able to hibernate, but sleep mode should work.

Comment: I do. I think. When I partitioned it I made a swap and root partition. Is there a way to check I have it enabled? I have 16GB ram and made a 16GB swap partition. It does show up as 15.4GB. Could that be why? Sleep also had the same affect I think. Will recheck soon.

Comment: The simplest check is to run `free -h`. The final line should be something like `Swap:          18G       329M        18G` (my current report). Alternatively `swapon` should report something like `/dev/sda7 partition 18.6G 329.1M   -1`.

Comment: @AFH The last line of `free -h` is `Swap: 14G 0B 14G` `swapon` just gives me the help list.

Comment: That seems OK. I use Ubuntu, also a Debian derivative, and I assumed that it would use the same `swapon`, wrongly as it seems.

Comment: @AFH So what do you think could be the issue then?

Comment: I don't have a lot to go on: see if the system logs reveal anything. You could try hibernating without closing the lid, which may cause undesirable side-effects on the hardware which recovery from hibernation doesn't handle; or see if you can get sleep mode to work: this will still put a small drain on the battery (unlike hibernation), but that would be preferable to crashing.

Comment: @AFH Added Error Log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27316/discussion-between-iprogram-and-afh).

Comment: I have had a similar problem on a non-Linux friendly piece of hardware.  I ended up disabling actions on lid close.  Of course this is a workaround, not a solution, but does keep the computer from freezing.

Comment: @Ned64 only issue with that is it still drains your battery life and if the computer gets warm the fans wont turn on will they?

Comment: @iProgram Yes, you are right. But, with a device where the battery lasts 12 hours in idle mode it did not matter to me... it might be different for you, of course, and I know it's a temporary workaround, not a solution.  The temperature in idle mode is very low indeed with these ULV CPUs, so that is not a problem, either.

Comment: @Ned64 What about if you shut the lid while running an intense program? Wouldn't that heat up the computer?

Comment: I am assuming here that you do not run a scientific calculation. When you visit a webpage or have a text processor open, and you do nothing -- it waits until you do something.  This waiting for an event is computationally inexpensive.  Try it out, and if the workaround does not work in your setup revert.

Comment: @Ned64 Cool! I should be fine then. If not I can get it to shutdown. This way I don't have to force shutdown.

Comment: OK, since you said this is a useful suggestion I will convert it into a solution, please see below.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for the problem is to disable any action which is triggered by closing the lid.  This can usually be set in the power options in your system settings interface.  You also need to make sure that the display automatically dims while idle, and that the computer does not auto-suspend after a certain period of time.

On modern computers (especially with ULV CPU) with low power consumption leaving the computer on does not take a lot of power at all.  Therefore you should be OK with this.  Exceptions are only a few websites (open web pages which make JavaScript or other computations without user interaction), you can try this out by running the command `top` in a terminal window (on newer systems `top -o %CPU` gives you better visibility of CPU-hungry processes).  There you can see whether a process like firefox is hogging a lot of CPU (like 50%) or the computer it is idling (no process over 10% or so).

This worked for myself on a similar machine, avoiding the crashes when suspend was tried and failed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have only up-voted this and not marked it as answered since I want to see if other people can find a solution. If I don't get a solution within a week I shall accept this.

Comment: Thanks, you are quite right.  Hope someone finds a true answer!